# How to set a boolean to true if the button is clicked?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set my `isApprove` boolean to true if the button is clicked for the current `id`.

Migration:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('approve_document', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('approve_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('requestedBy')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('approve_id')->references('id')->on('approves')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('requestedBy')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->boolean('isApprove');

        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('dateModified')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function documentsSentForApproval()
{

    $pendingDocumentLists = DB::table('approve_document')
    ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'approve_document.dateReceived', 'documents.id', 'approves.approver_id', 'approve_document.document_id', 'approve_document.isApprove')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approve_document.document_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
    ->join('approves', 'approves.id', '=', 'approve_document.approve_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
    ->get();


    return view ('document.pending')
    ->with('pendingDocumentLists', $pendingDocumentLists);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($pendingDocumentLists as $list)
        <tr class = "info">

            <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{ strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ date('M, j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
            <td>

                <a href = "{{ route ('document.viewPending', $list->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-open"> Read</button></a>

                <a href = ""><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> Edit</button></a>

                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</button>

                @if (Auth::id() == $list->approver_id)

                    <a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->document_id) }}">
                        <button type = "submit" onclick = "approveFunction()" class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Approve</button>
                    </a>

                    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"> Reject</button>

                @endif

            </td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm little bit stuck here in my if condition. Where if I hit the **Approve** button I'm getting the current id of the `document` but I need to set a condition here to set it `isApprove` to true. Any help how can I achieve this?

Logic:

If `($list->document_id)` is approve. Set `isApprove` column to true for the current `document_id`

Answer (score 0):

Mayb you looking this:

add new

```
<input type="hidden" name="approved" value="0">
```

when click button  with javascript change value to 1;

---

Or you can send via ajax, but don't forget add token.

P.s true and false can be replaced with 1 ad 0

Comment: Thanks for this. The current value at my db is 0. So I think I should change to value to `1`.

Comment: Yes. You should.

$approved = 1

will works as $approved = true

mysql boolean save as TINYINT

Comment: Should I include this input type = "hidden" under my view or javascript function?

Comment: you can include with view, and with javascript button click event change value